# Why do some reciters add echo to Quranic recitations?

Tags: halal-haram, quran-recitation, bidah

This has been an issue annoying me lately, that sometimes when you are praying in a Mosque or listening to a Quranic recording you can clearly tell that the echo is an added sound and not produced naturally, my questions are:

1. Why do they do this?
2. Do they think that they are adding greatness to the word of Allah? Allah's words are already great!
3. Is it not an innovation "Bidah"?
4. Is it not Haram?

Comment: I think that's a question of taste. I dislike it too

Answer (score 1):

I asked a mufti about it, and his reply was that
**People who are doing these things they are not supposed to do so, they are supposed to recite quran beautifully, not to add artificial sounds in it. And also not to add sounds which disturbs the beauty of recitation, and just focuses on how long one can recite and things like that.
 This thing was first started in areas around miser(egypt) and the ulama of haramain(makkah and madinah) had condemned them in that time when it began.

As a summary, it is not good thing to do, and we do not give a strict ruling on it to be haraam either. And we ask them to stop doing this and we pray to Allah to guide them.**

### Allah knows best